# Keep jsonschema from always making requests to URI

Tags: python, python-3.x, jsonschema

### Background

I am trying to validate a JSON file using [jsonchema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema). However, the library is trying to make a GET request and I want to avoid that.

```
from jsonschema import validate

point_schema = {
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/point",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {"x": {"type": "number"}, "y": {"type": "number"}},
    "required": ["x", "y"],
}

polygon_schema = {
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/polygon",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {"$ref": "https://example.com/schemas/point"},
}

a_polygon = [{'x': 1, 'y': 2}, {'x': 3, 'y': 4}, {'x': 1, 'y': 2}]

validate(instance=a_polygon, schema=polygon_schema)
```

### Error

I am trying to connect both schemas using a `$ref` key from the spec:

- https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html?highlight=ref#ref

Unfortunately for me, this means the library will make a GET request to the URI specified and try to decode it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 777, in resolve_from_url
    document = self.resolve_remote(url)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 860, in resolve_remote
    result = requests.get(uri).json()
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 932, in validate
    error = exceptions.best_match(validator.iter_errors(instance))
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/exceptions.py", line 367, in best_match
    best = next(errors, None)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 328, in iter_errors
    for error in errors:
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/_validators.py", line 81, in items
    for error in validator.descend(item, items, path=index):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 344, in descend
    for error in self.iter_errors(instance, schema):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 328, in iter_errors
    for error in errors:
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/_validators.py", line 259, in ref
    scope, resolved = validator.resolver.resolve(ref)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 766, in resolve
    return url, self._remote_cache(url)
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/myapp-py/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 779, in resolve_from_url
    raise exceptions.RefResolutionError(exc)
jsonschema.exceptions.RefResolutionError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I don't want this, I just want the `polygon` schema to reference the  `point` schema that is right above (as for this purpose, a polygon is a list of points).

In fact, these schemas are in the same file.

### Questions

I could always do the following:

```
point_schema = {
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/point",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {"x": {"type": "number"}, "y": {"type": "number"}},
    "required": ["x", "y"],
}

polygon_schema = {
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemas/polygon",
    "type": "array",
    "items": point_schema,
}
```

And this would technically work.

However I would simply be build a bigger dictionary and I would not be using the spec as it was designed to.

How can I use the spec to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide your other schemas to the implementation.

With this implementation, you must provide a [RefResolver](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/references/#resolving-json-references) to the [validate function](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.validate).

You'll need to either provide a single `base_uri` and `referrer` (the schema), or a `store` which contains a dictionary of URI to schema.

Additionally, you may handle protocols with a function.

Your RefResolver would look like the following...

`refResolver = jsonschema.RefResolver(referrer=point_schema, base_uri='https://example.com/schemas/point'`

Comment: So, technically: `validate(instance=a_polygon, schema=polygon_schema, resolver=refResolver)`

Comment: But what if I need multiple `refResolver`s ? How would I pass them? Can you give an example?

Comment: In that case you'd need to provide a `store`, which is a dictionary where the keys are URIs (like `base_uri`) and the values are the schemas (like `referrer`). I could provide you an example, but I don't know if it would work, as I don't write python and have no environment set up to test any python code.

Comment: If this doesn't help, there are some examples where people have built up a store from files in loops if you search for RefResolver. If this doesn't help, JSON Schema has a slack server where the author of this module can be found. https://json-schema.org/slack